# Check MethodInfo instance is implementation of interface generic method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I has interface

```
public interface ITest
{
    Task<bool> MyMethod1<T>(string key, out T value);
    Task<bool> MyMethod2<T>(string key, out T value);
}
```

And they implementation

```
public class TestImpl : ITest
{
    public Task<bool> MyMethod1<T>(string key, out T value) // Implements interface
    {
        // Skipped
    }

    public Task<bool> MyMethod1<T>(string key, T value) // Does not implements interface
    {
        // Skipped
    }

    public Task<bool> MyMethod2<T>(string key, out T value) // Implements interface
    {
        // Skipped
    }

    public Task<bool> MyMethod2<T>(string key, T value) // Does not implements interface
    {
        // Skipped
    }
}
```

I need to check that specified instance of MethodInfo is method implementation of ITest interface.

For example:

```
void DoWork(MethodInfo methodInfo)
{
    if (...) // Check methodInfo is implementation of any method declared in ITest interface
    {
        /* Do something */
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea, but I don't know if it fits your situation
Why you don't get type of the implementation `the class` and then you get the interface you are interested in by its name `nameof(ITest)` and then you iterate through all methods of this interface which is implemented by that type like the following:

```
foreach(var methodInfo in typeof(TestImpl).GetInterface(nameof(ITest)).GetMethods())
{

}
```

This is very easy idea, the fact that you didn't hard-coded the interface name in the `foreach` loop it is good too.
If it didn't fit your situation, please consider adding more details to your question so I can think about a different idea and edit this answer, or someone can help you.
**EDIT**
Or you can get the concrete class type by the property `ReflectedType` and then you can get a 'reflection-mapping' of the methods of this type based on specific interface type using `GetInterfaceMap` method, this method will then returns the methods which is implemented for this interface type in this concrete class type, you can then simply use the method `Contains` to check for specific `MethodInfo` instance as you asked. Hope this helped you now.

```
static bool IsMethodImplementationOfInterface(Type interfaceType,MethodInfo method)
{
    return method.ReflectedType.GetInterfaceMap(interfaceType).TargetMethods.Contains(method);
}

foreach (var methodInfo in typeof(TestImpl).GetMethods())
{
    if (IsMethodImplementationOfInterface(typeof(ITest), methodInfo))
    {
        //Logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my case this impossible, because i need check MethodInfo passed by 3rd-party library

Comment: Provided better example

Comment: I've updated my answer, tell me if this helped you now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetInterfaceMap:

```
var testImpl = new TestImpl();
        var interfaceTargeMethods = testImpl.GetType().GetInterfaceMap(typeof(ITest)).TargetMethods;

        foreach (var methodInfo in testImpl.GetType().GetMethods())
        {
            if (interfaceTargeMethods.Contains(methodInfo))
            {
                // do something...
            }    
        }
```